# How to extract a value from xpath when there are multiple namespaces defined at different levels?

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

This is the XML result I got from my server.

```
<ns1:tag1 xmlns:ns1="http://samples.org">
  <ns2:tag2 xmlns:ns2="http://samples.com">
    <ns3:tag3 xmlns:ns3="http://samples.edu">chanaka</ns3:tag3>
  </ns2:tag2>
</ns1:tag1>
```

Here I want to get the value tag3 from the xpath expression. I have tried the following xpath expression but it didn't work.

```
//ns1:tag1/ns2:tag2/ns3:tag3
```

But when I declare all the namespaces at the root level, this expression gave the result.

Comment: I am using Java programming language ...

Comment: "this expression gave the result." -- gave what result? And how does your Java code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is some cleaner way how to do it (I hope someone else knows) but following could also make a job:

```
//ns1:tag1/node()[local-name() = 'tag2' and namespace-uri() = 'http://samples.com']/node()[local-name() = 'tag3' and namespace-uri() = 'http://samples.edu']
```